# Basis of a tensor

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I'm new to tensors, and I need to understand what a certain basis actually is, how to visualise it.

Say we have the $r$-dimensional vector space $T_p M$ and $n$-dimensional dual space $T^{*}_p M$. They have bases $\big\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{b_1}},...,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{b_r}} \big\}$ and $\big\{ \mathrm{d}x^{a_1},...,\mathrm{d}x^{a_n} \big\}$, respectively (right?).

Now a $(r,n)$-tensor is the map $T: \otimes^r T_p M \otimes^n T^{*}_p M \to \mathbb{R}$, which can be expanded in a basis $\big\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{b_1}} \otimes ... \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{b_r}} \otimes \mathrm{d}x^{a_1} \otimes ... \otimes \mathrm{d}x^{a_n} \big\}$.

How to 'write out' the basis i.e. what are it's elements? How to visualise it?

Comment: I am familiar with tensor products, and to me, the basis of the second type does not make sense, it contains too many $\otimes$es. The basis of the first type makes perfectly sense. The general element of $V\otimes W$ has the form $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\otimes w_i$ with $n \in \mathbb N_0,\ v_i \in V,\ w_i \in W$. The elements of the basis of the second type are definitely not of this form.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just realised myself that I confused two things. I think I might need to rephrase the question..

Comment: To begin, the $T_pM$ and $T_p^*M$ have the same dimension.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Take, for example the mixed $(2,1)$-tensors
$$T={T_{i_1i_2}}^{j_1}dx^{i_1}\otimes dx^{i_2}\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j_1}},$$ 
as **tri-indexed linear combination** on the basis $dx^{i_1}\otimes dx^{i_2}\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j_1}}$.

These basis, as **tri-linear maps** $T_pM\times T_pM\times T_p^*M\to{\mathbb{R}}$, work via
$$dx^{i_1}\otimes dx^{i_2}\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j_1}}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{a_1}},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{a_2}},dx^{b_1}\right)=\delta^{i_1}_{a_1}\delta^{i_2}_{a_2}\delta^{b_1}_{j_1}.$$

Comment: a general $(n,r)$-tensor is $T={T_{i_1\cdots i_n}}^{j_1\cdots j_r}dx^{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes dx^{i_n}\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j_1}}\otimes\cdots\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j_r}},$